# Run specific code before specific context only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to run a specific block of code before one specific context, and it should run only once. I tried to use metadata for context block, but it calls my block of code before every example.

```
before do |context|
  p 'test test' if context.medata[:something]
end
...
describe '#execute' do
  context 'header with timelog fields', :something do
    it '123' do
      expect(true).to eq true
    end
    it '234' do
      expect(true).to eq true
    end
   end
end
```

`test test` appears twice when I run rspec.

Comment: Can you have several such contexts? If yes, how many times do you want the block to run then?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is medata?

Answer (score 1):

In `rspec`, writing `before` is shorthand for `before(:each)`.

What you need to use, instead, is a `before(:all)`:

```
describe '#execute' do
  context 'header with timelog fields' do
    before(:all) do
      p 'test test'
    end

    it '123' do
      expect(true).to eq true
    end
    it '234' do
      expect(true).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: **However**, you need to be careful when writing code like this! It is *usually* considered bad to change the "global state" of the system in a test. You should "leave the system exactly as you found it", otherwise you may have intermittent test failures caused by tests running in a random order.

Comment: There are *some* legitimate use cases for this pattern, though. Depending on what the `before(:all)` is actually doing, consider also defining an `after(:all)` to "reset" the system back to its normal state.